# MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN not being called even though I return true for it

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have an `onTouchListener` for my `LinearLayout` of `ListView`s and I am trying to use the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` data to detect when a user has swiped to the next `ListView`. However, the `MotionEvent` never equals `ACTION_DOWN`, although `ACTION_UP` works perfectly. After a lot of googling, the only solution I could find is to return true when the event is called, but I was already doing that. Here is my `onTouchListener` code

```
View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                downX = event.getX();
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                upX = event.getX();
                if(userSwipedFarEnough)
                    doStuff()
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

    };
```

Comment: On which view u have set this listener?..where in the hierarchy?try some log like action before all your code

Comment: strange, i deleted my answer as i was wrong, +1. btw is the view you are setting the touch listener to a `ViewGroup`? or just a `View`?

Comment: It is a LinearLayout view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out what was happening, the scrollview for my listview was somehow stealing the action_down so it wasn't being called. I realized it when I had an empty listview and the scrolling worked.

Answer (score 0):

The onTouch gets called several times depending on the touch type, ACTION_DOWN ACTION_UP ACTION_MOVE and all these could happen together. I would say take out the else if and just use an if so it catches both actions

Comment: I tried this and it did not fix the issue, there must be something else...but thank you for your reply

Comment: did you try if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is extending the ScrollView:

```
interface MyScrollViewActionDownListener{
    fun onActionDown()
}

class MyScrollView: ScrollView
{
    private var mActionDownListener: MyScrollViewActionDownListener? = null
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int): super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)
    constructor(context: Context):super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet):super(context,attributeSet)

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if(ev!!.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mActionDownListener?.onActionDown()
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }

    fun setActionDownListener(listener: MyScrollViewActionDownListener){
        this.mActionDownListener = listener
    }
}
```